# Cypress Windows - Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)

Tags: node.js, cypress, firewall, errno, econnreset

I have installed Cypress on my PC but when I try to use it at the end of test execution, it fails due to following error:

Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)
{
errno: -4077,
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read'
}
Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)

Someone could you help me?

N.B. I try to change also the browser version and the cypress versions used without success.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for editing my original answer, as I don't have a reputation I'm unable to upvote or comment to the original thread.
I believe this is a duplicate of this post (see [Cypress ECONNRESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489215/why-does-cypress-get-econnreset-when-accessing-api-cypress-io-port-443/72041172#72041172)

Answer (score 1):

Currently the easiest workaround is to just switch to the Electron browser (see image below).

Based on other questions and answers, the cause of this is Sophos anti-virus software.

See:

- [Sophos Issue 134136](https://community.sophos.com/intercept-x-endpoint/f/discussions/134136/sophos-network-threat-detection-is-blocking-cypress-automation-tool)
- [Cypress GitHub Issue 14175](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/14175)

[image]